# Double Quotes shown as some strange characters - PHP, HTML

Tags: php, zend-framework, html-entities, double-quotes

If you notice the two line below, the double quotes are not the same. the first one is what i have a problem with. They are shown as strange characters like - â��. But the secound line double quotes is just fine.

“this is line 1.”

and

"this is line 2."

What is the difference between the two double quotes, and how can the special characters be prevented?

Comment: could you provide a minimal PHP example, showing what exactly you do and where the error occurs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In line 1, those quotes are sometimes called "smart quotes".  They are ascii code #147 and #148.

In line 2, those are "normal" quotes, ascii code #34.

Because character definition beyond ascii code #127 can become somewhat arbritrary depending on the font used, I try to avoid using the smart quote characters.

Micorosoft Word will (infamously) convert normal quotes to "smart quotes".  This "feature" can be turned off in settings.

Comment: Yes, thats is correct. But how do i handle this in PHP, as the users of my website input such data. and i need to show it in a view page in the correct format.

Comment: do i need to apply any function to the string with the smart quotes, while storing it in the database?

Comment: While processing the POST data, I would replace those characters:
$user_input = str_replace("“", "\"", $user_input)
$user_input = str_replace("”", "\"", $user_input)
(that is ugly, shown in 2 steps for clarity)

Answer (score 2):

You should make sure, your PHP script uses utf-8, as well as the html meta tag says utf-8.

For the first thing, try in PHP (before any output occurs)

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

In php, you can escape most HTML specialchars with "htmlentities". See http://php.net/manual/de/function.htmlentities.php

Comment: I have already added UTF-8 in the header. As mentioned in the other two answers, the text is being copied from MS word, but it is the user of the site that do it. and i only want to handle it.

Comment: do i need to apply any function to the string with the smart quotes, while storing it in the database?

Comment: Is your database also using utf-8? Does it look correct in the db, when e.g. reading with phpmyadmin?

Comment: No it does not look,the way it is supposed to. it has some different symbols like a euro etc.

Comment: So you got your problem. At least a part of it. Which db are you using? Check if the tables are stored as UTF8 and if you're connection is using utf8. Then, if the string is correct when inserting and retrieving again, the rest is HTML encoding, but should work if the HTML is also sent as UTF8.

Answer (score 1):

First line you copied probably from `MS word/MS Excel`. Their double quotes are different and will not parse properly using HTTP. You need to convert them using `UTF-8 charset` and then display on your website.

Comment: do i need to apply any function to the string with the smart quotes, while storing it in the database?

Answer (score 0):

This issue occurred to me  when I copy pasted text text from word document to label. If you observe carefully Word document double quotes looked little curvy opposed to HTML double quotes. Just removing copy pasted doubled quotes and typing again helped.   ” - This from Word ." - This is from HTML . You can see the difference yourselves